# Computer to AVR to 4K Smart TV surround sound setup

Tags: hdmi

I'm trying to find the perfect settings for watching downloaded movies in 7.1 format. I have an older computer, HP ENVY with GTX 1080 GPU, 32 Gig ram, runs 4K no problem. Just purchased DENON AVR S970H AVR, with brand new Samsung 4K TV.
To put it bluntly, there are so many settings on that AVR and the TV for settings, it gets confusing. I have Windows 10 set to surround 7.1, and HRD is on. VLC just upgraded to 3.0, but all I have set there for audio is " always decode in Dolby surround". Some movies sound pretty good, some don't. My old Denon AVR S740H would tell me what my input signal was ... DTS, Dolby, DTS-X, Dolby ATMOS, so could set the amp to that, but this brand new 970 just shows " PCM " as input signal all the time but it will show all the speakers as active speakers in input and the proper speakers are highlighted for actual output...I'm to the point now where I have a button that says "Direct", "Pure Direct" and "Auto" ... I just leave it on Auto. I was wondering if it would make sense to burn my downloaded 4K movies onto a flash drive, and just plug the flash drive into the back of the TV and let eARC send the proper sound signal down to the AVR?  I even went out and bought top of the line, 8K HDMI cables to connect all 3 units, because the " HDMI " test built into the TV said my cables failed. I have read the AVR manual, I have read the TV manual many times...there's just so many possible setups.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Audio/Video Receiver (AVR) that's capable of decoding the audio stream, the best practice is to simply pass the bitstream to the AVR to permit the AVR to decode and handle it. Windows Audio enhancement and Spatial sound settings may cause Windows to force decoding and should be disabled while setting up.

In VLC, or other audio/video applications, you'll need to find the setting that permits audio passthrough. This will vary per application. In VLC, look for a setting called "HDMI/SPDIF Passthrough" in the audio output module.

Your AVR displaying PCM with all speakers driven indicates that your computer is decoding the audio instead of passing the audio stream to the AVR.

If your TV and AVR both support eARC, you might want to run your HDMI sources directly to the TV and use the eARC output of the TV to provide the audio stream to the AVR. The primary reason to do this is to bypass whatever resolution/VRR/HDR/HDMI signal limits are imposed by the AVR to permit optimal picture and audio quality - this frees you from upgrading the AVR until a newer audio standard is introduced. It will also reduce the number of video stops in the signal chain, which *can* improve video signal stability (but it could make it worse, especially if you need to use a longer cable - most AVRs also act as an HDMI signal equalizer). Poor signal stability is typically indicated by dots, blanking, or no signal shown on the display. This configuration would then use the TV to switch input sources instead of the AVR. The downsides are that most TV sets have fewer HDMI sources than AVRs, running many HDMI cables to your TV may be harder/messier (especially if your TV is wall mounted), and loss of your AVR's On-Screen Display (OSD)/guide for setup of the AVR.